# Generating an Average Plane from a Set of Points

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to generate a plane in 3D space from a set of points where the origin is averaged between those points according to the known normal of that plane. Okay, I don't whether I could express my self well enough so I try to explain it in a two dimensional space first.

Let's suppose we have a set of points and want to average there positions according to one of the axis (let's say the y-axis):

```
5| x      x                      <-- The points to be averaged
4|    x
3|
2|         x
1|  x              x
 ------------------------------
```

And here is how it would look after the averaging

```
5|                               <-- The points to be averaged
4|                               
3| xx x   xx       x
2|         
1|                
 ------------------------------
```

The "plane" could then be described by any point at y=3 and the normal of the x-axis, right? Okay now I wan't to do the same thing in a 3D space. The normal of the resulting plane is always given, so are the points. But how do I calculate this average plane? I tried finding a solution online (maybe I searched for the wrong thing), however I couldn't find any solution to that.

Comment: The right keyword is (IMHO) "Least Squares Approximation"

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Okay, I tried understanding this Approximation Method, by I couldn't figure out how that could help me to get the solution to the problem. Could you please explain how this helps me finding that plane? (Also in mind that the normal to the plane is already given)

Comment: Is the normal to be determined from the point locations, or is the fixed (predefined) and you are just looking for a point through the plane?

Comment: @ja72 Yes, the normal is predefined. Sorry, I'm sometimes not that good at expressing myself.

Comment: Maybe you should edit the title. What you are looking for is a _projection_ of 3D points onto a fixed plane. The title sais "generate a plane from points" but this is not what you are asking.

Comment: @ja72 But is the plane fixed? To describe a plane I need a origin and its normal, but I only have one of them - the normal vector. The origin shell be calculated as the average of the points according to the normal.

Comment: Is this what you have trouble with? Calculating the average of the points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the normal direction $\mathbf{n} = (n_x,n_y,n_z)$ and the average location (point *A*) of all the points $\mathbf{r}_A = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf{r}_i$ then the plane is defined mathematically as $$ \mathbf{n} \cdot \left( \mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_A \right) =0 $$

where $\mathbf{r}=(x,y,z)$ would describe *any* location on the point, and $\cdot$ is the inner vector product.

Now to project your existing points $\mathbf{r}_i$ *onto* the plane, subtract their distance to the plane along the normal $\mathbf{n}$. The distance is $$d_i =\mathbf{n} \cdot \left( \mathbf{r}_i - \mathbf{r}_A \right)$$

So each point projected onto the plane becomes

$$ \begin{align} \mathbf{r}_i^{\rm plane} & = \mathbf{r}_i - d_i\, \mathbf{n} \\
& = \mathbf{r}_i - \left(\mathbf{n} \cdot \left( \mathbf{r}_i - \mathbf{r}_A \right) \right) \mathbf{n} 
\end{align}$$

Comment: Oh okay, great! I had this misconception in my mind the whole time that I need to take the normal into account, when calculating the point average (Don't ask me why). Sometimes it's helpful to just here someone else ask you a small question to help you realize the actual problem. Thank you for that!

Comment: Gad to be of service. I guess mathematically you might try to prove that $\mathbf{r}_A$ minimizes $\sum | d_i |^2$. Don't ask me how, I just know intuitively that the average point minimizes the deviation of the distances in _any_ direction including the one that matters (plane normal). Thank you for the diagram because otherwise I wouldn't have understood what you were asking.